# Receiving UIPasteboard (generalPasteboard) notification while in the background

Tags: cocoa-touch, uipasteboard, generalpasteboard

In there a way to do this? I register my object for `UIPasteboardChangedNotification` at launch time, but when sending it to the background and opening (for instance) Safari and copying some text, my handler never gets called.
(I'm using just the simulator for now).

I've used both:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
    selector:@selector(pasteboardNotificationReceived:) 
    name:UIPasteboardChangedNotification 
    object:[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard]];
```

and:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
    selector:@selector(pasteboardNotificationReceived:) 
    name:UIPasteboardChangedNotification 
    object:nil ];
```

to register my handler.

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? I am also trying to accomplish this. http://cl.ly/69a4 If you have found the answer, would you mind sharing it with me?

Comment: I'm having this same problem. Have you or anyone filed a bug report with Apple?

Answer (score 12):

I had the same problem. According to the [UIPasteboard Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPasteboard_Class/Reference.html) documentation for the `changeCount` property (emphasis is mine):

> Whenever the contents of a pasteboard changes—specifically, when pasteboard items are added, modified, or removed—UIPasteboard increments the value of this property. After it increments the change count, UIPasteboard posts the notifications named UIPasteboardChangedNotification (for additions and modifications) and UIPasteboardRemovedNotification (for removals). ... The class also updates the change count **when an application reactivates and another application has changed the pasteboard contents.** When users restart a device, the change count is reset to zero.

I had read this to mean that my application would receive `UIPasteboardChangedNotification` notifications once my app was reactivated. A careful reading reveals, however, that it is only the `changeCount` that is updated when the app is reactivated.

I dealt with this by tracking the pasteboard's `changeCount` in my app delegate and posting the expected notification when I find the `changeCount` has been changed while the app was in the background.

In the app delegate's interface:

```
NSUInteger pasteboardChangeCount_;
```

And in the app delegate's implementation:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication*)application
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)launchOptions {
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
   addObserver:self
   selector:@selector(pasteboardChangedNotification:)
   name:UIPasteboardChangedNotification
   object:[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard]];
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
   addObserver:self
   selector:@selector(pasteboardChangedNotification:)
   name:UIPasteboardRemovedNotification
   object:[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard]];

  ...
}

- (void)pasteboardChangedNotification:(NSNotification*)notification {
  pasteboardChangeCount_ = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard].changeCount;
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication*)application {
  if (pasteboardChangeCount_ != [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard].changeCount) {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
     postNotificationName:UIPasteboardChangedNotification
     object:[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard]];
  }
}
```

Comment: It works BUT this solution can not monitor the notification during your app is under background, it only triggered when you reactive your app.