# iOS - detect when user copy to clipboard - [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard]

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, copy-paste, uipasteboard

quick easy question

while using a WebView with some text in it - the user can select a snippet of text from it
and press a UIButton which I created - running the following action:

```
-(IBAction)copyToClip
{
    NSString *copyClip = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard].string;
    NSLog(@"Clip = %@",copyClip);
    // (works fine)
}
```

I would like to call the same function without a UIButton, thus when the user did a "copy" action it will activate the above code. (I assume a listener)

what would be the appropriate listener for this?

Comment: have you check these notifications:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4240087/receiving-uipasteboard-generalpasteboard-notification-while-in-the-background ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use NSNotificationCenter and register for UIPasteboardChangedNotification:
http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPasteboard_Class/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/data/UIPasteboardChangedNotification

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:object selector:@selector(copyToClip) name:UIPasteboardChangedNotification object:nil];
```

Comment: Hey, Is it working when user get copy any thing in any other app.

Comment: What about Swift 4 version?

Answer (score 0):

If someone is interested in the Xamarin/C# version:

```
NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.AddObserver(UIPasteboard.ChangedNotification, 
            notification => { 
                // custom code here
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5**

[**`UIPasteboard.changedNotification`**](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipasteboard/1622104-changednotification/)

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(handleCopy), name: UIPasteboard.changedNotification, object: nil)

@objc func handleCopy(sender: NSNotification) {
    // Handle new pasteboard
    print("pasteboard changed: \(UIPasteboard.general.items.first)")
}
```

Don't forget to add `@objc` to your handler so the method is visible to the objective-C selector.