# How to get data(string,url,image,etc) from UIPasteboard while App is in Background State

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, uipasteboard

i was digging on `"How to get data from UIPasteboard while App is in background state"` but could not find something useful.
i followed this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8941860/ios-detect-when-user-copy-to-clipboard-uipasteboard-generalpasteboard)
and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11864553/ios-http-request-while-in-background) but not helpful. any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Should see this http://blog.daanraman.com/coding/monitor-the-ios-pasteboard-while-running-in-the-background/

Comment: @HarvantS. , thanks for sooner reply :)

Comment: That tutorial have every thing you want. I just tested on device.

Comment: @HarvantS. , please, add as answer and i will accept it as answer :)

Comment: Ok so answer is deleted. You asked about pasteboard notification? what do you want to know. As i know there are 4 type of notifications.

Answer (score 0):

[Daan Raman](https://twitter.com/daanraman) had a tutorial [here](http://blog.daanraman.com/coding/monitor-the-ios-pasteboard-while-running-in-the-background/). It have everything you want.

There are total 4 type of UIPasteboardNotifications

```
UIPasteboardChangedNotification;
UIPasteboardChangedTypesAddedKey;
UIPasteboardChangedTypesRemovedKey;
UIPasteboardRemovedNotification;
```

`UIPasteboardChangedNotification` generate notification when the pasteboard item changed. `UIPasteboardChangedTypesRemovedKey` and `UIPasteboardRemovedNotification` are the changes which are mode in pasteboard dictionary. `UIPasteboardRemovedNotification` when an app remove the pasteboard object.